# ViewModelLocator in PRISM (Unity) does not work in modules

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodellocator

I am following the [Brian Lagunas's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfBy2nfykqY) and have a question.

We have a small application setup with PRISM 6 and Unity bootstrapper. I want to use the `ViewModelLocator` to bind a `ViewModel` to my view. This works in the "base module" (the one with Shell and bootstrapper), but it seems that there are some issues when using it in other modules.

Below you can find the classes for `View` (XAML and code behind) and for `ViewModel`. The binding works if I set the `DataContext` in the code behind manually. while debugging the code I found out that the `ViewModel` class is never instantiated so I guess the `VML` cannot find the VM because of wrong configuration. But as far as I can see the naming conventions are fulfilled.

Can you find the issue or have an idea what configuration I did forget?

View(code behind):

```
namespace CommunicationModule.Views
{
    public partial class CommunicationView : UserControl, IView
    { 
            public CommunicationView()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }     
        }
}
```

View XAML:

```
  <UserControl
     x:Class="CommunicationModule.Views.CommunicationView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:View="clr-namespace:CommunicationModule.Views"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ModelList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="320" Height="300">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate">
                <Border Name="border" BorderBrush="DarkSlateBlue" BorderThickness="2" 
                 CornerRadius="2" Padding="5" Margin="5">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="30"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Path=IconUri}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Title}" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=ContentShort}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- UI -->

        <DockPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,10,0">
            <!-- Title -->
            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top" FontSize="18" Margin="5" Content="Wichtige Meldungen"/>

            <!-- Data template is specified by the ItemTemplate attribute -->
            <ScrollViewer>
                <ListBox Name="listBox"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate}" 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
            Margin="5,0,5,5" Width="280"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ViewModel:

```
namespace CommunicationModule.ViewModels
{
    public class CommunicationViewViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private List<CommunicationModel> _modelList = (new CommunicationModelBO()).getCommunicationItems(); //= new List<CommunicationModel>();
        private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

        public List<CommunicationModel> ModelList
        {
            get { return _modelList; }
            set { SetProperty<List<CommunicationModel>>(ref _modelList, value); }
        }

        public CommunicationViewViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
        {
          _regionManager = regionManager;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show you `ViewModalLocator` implementation

Comment: What kind of implementation do you mean? I do not have a custom implementation of the VML. I have followed the instruction from Brian Lagunas [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfBy2nfykqY) and thought using the correct namespaces and set AutoWireModel=true would be enough. For my base module it works fine for the my shell class.

Answer (score 4):

You can not let your usercontrol's name end with `View`，if you do so, the `AutoWireViewModel` won't work. So please change your usercontrols name to `Communication` and viewmodels name to `CommunicationViewModel`.